# How to launch form2 from form1 in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, parent-child

OK, I am about 1 week into programming in C# ever...
I am writing a GUI application that has two forms.
`Form1` is the main form, and have quite a bit of codes that are working nicely.
`Form2` is supposed to be launched, when Form1 is handling exception..

`Form1` and `Form2` are both created in VS Solution Explorer, so they are not code created on the fly.

In Form1.cs ...

```
namespace Launcher
{
    public partial class Form1: Form  
    {  
        // ...  
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try  
            {  
                //some codes  
            }  
            catch (SomeException)  
            {  
                Form Form2 = new Form();  
                Form2.Show();  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition .. in Program.cs ..

```
using System.Windows.Forms;  

namespace LauncherCSharp  
{
    static class Program  
    {
    /// <summary>  
    /// The main entry point for the application.  
    /// </summary>  

        static void Main()  
        {  
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();  
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);  
            Application.Run(new Form1());  
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is .. `Form2.Show()` will pop up a brand new `Form2`, and not the one I've defined in Solution Explorer. I think this is related to the new `Form()` line above, but if I don't have this new `Form()` line, the compiler complained about `Form2.Show()` ..Cannot access non-static method "show" in static context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't actually creating Form2

Your code

```
Form Form2 = new Form();
```

Should probably be

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
```

or replace Form2 with the actual name of your form2.

In C#, we create an instances of an object (in your case the object is the form) by the following syntax

```
ObjectName yourVariableName = new ObjectName();
```

We can then refer to this object by using the "yourVariableName".
e.g.

```
yourVariableName.Show(); // Show the form
```

Comment: @user3023351, If it's the answer you needed, please consider accepting it as the accepted answer.